# Using feet latitude/longitude and flat distance between to approximate spherical distance between two points, huge error why?

Tags: geometry, spherical-geometry

Setup: you 2 have points on the surface of the Earth that are close to each other, say 30N100W and 30.1N100.2W, in decimal degrees.

Step 1: find the feet latitude/longitude for each point.  For latitude, 1 degree is approximately 365,229', and longitude is approximately 365,229'*cos(latitude). [EDIT: well turns out the circumference of 30N is about 30km more than if you were to treat the Earth as a sphere, but that's like a .1% difference, so I'll disregard]

- This makes the first point ~10,956,870' north of the equator, and ~31,629,759' west of there
- The second point is ~10,993,393' north of the equator, and ~31,661,034 west of there

Step 2: good ol' 2-dimensional distance equation gives ~48,083' apart

Step 3: confirm with an online latitude/longitude distance calculator, plugging in the original 30N100W and 30.1N100.2W, and it instead gives ~72,917'!

Surely approximating the surface of a sphere by a plane on such a small area wouldn't be so far off???  So the real question is... why the huge discrepancy?

Comment: The issue is that 100 degrees "West of there" is West of the Greenwich meridian, and the Earth's curvature is pretty significant on that scale. If you just define the first point to be the zero of longitude you get an answer of 73046 feet. My calculation using spherical trigonometry gives 73018 feet, so the pythagorean calculation is only off by 28 feet.

Comment: How did you get 31,661,034? That is significantly less than 365,229*cos(latitude)*101.2. It looks like the discrepancy is a simple arithmetic error, not so much an error in your method. Errors like this may be less likely if you take the differences of latitude and longitude in degrees first, then convert to feet.

Comment: @WW1 thanks! So hmm the problem is with R*cos(latitude) eh? Can’t treat the Earth like a circle. What should I have used? My google-fu is failing me. 

And David K I’ll have to run it again when I’m at my computer but it’s 100.2, not 101.2.

Comment: @danzibr. your formulas are all OK, you just need to realize that those 31.6 million feet lengths are along differently sized circles, you can't figure out the East-West distance by just subtracting the two lengths. One way to get MUCH closer would be to calculate the East-West distance between $(30, 100)$ and $(30, 100.2)$ and use that in your 2-D calculation.

Comment: Another method would be to recognize that the distance between $(30, 100)$ and $(30.1, 100.2)$ is exactly the same as the distance between $(30, 0)$ and $(30.1, 0.2)$. If you repeat your calculation for those two points your answer will be very close to the correct value.

Comment: @WW1 "those 31.6 million feet lengths are along differently sized circles." Ahh, so... the arc length from the Prime Meridian so far west is going to be quite different even for very small differences in latitudes. But then that makes it seem, for example, 30.1N100W would be not be directly north of 30N100W...
I suppose I still don't see the exact error/how to do it right.  Something like using different coordinates/haversines/whatever seems like a workaround.

Comment: 31,661,034  is significantly less than 365,229*cos(latitude)*100.2 too. It's more like 365,229*cos(latitude)*100.1.

Comment: Suggestion: see the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Flat-surface_formulae

Comment: @danzibr $(30.1, 100)$ IS due North of $(30, 100)$ (so East-West distance is zero.)
However $(30.1, 100)$ is 31.597 million feet West of Greenwich and $(30, 100)$ is 31.629 million feet West of Greenwich, so you can see that subtracting those distances will NOT give you the East West distance between those 2 points.

Comment: @WW1 yes indeed the difference doesn’t give you the distance between the points. But *why* does that not work?